# How can i get this type of plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need a plugin in wordpress which turns around the circle.
Here is the image link http://tinypic.com/r/2z4mvk8/8

Comment: By searching on Google ;)

Comment: I dont know how to search for this plugin. I Mean name for that

Comment: you can use this photo gallery https://wordpress.org/plugins/photo-gallery . Also from wordpress.org you will find more.

Comment: I think you mean you want a knob element: http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/.

Include it in your wordpress theme, and create a simple shortcode that will do what you need. Initialize it with a jquery and you're done.

Answer (score -1):

There is a wordpress plugin CC Circle Progress Bar which will work for you.
Here is the link:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/cc-circle-progress-bar/

Comment: thnq very much for your suggestion :)